# Hiding overflow on body breaks CSS transitions

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am making a type of modal using with the CSS3 transition property, and would like to prevent body from scrolling when the modal is opened. When Javascript adds a "noscroll" class to body, all of the CSS transitions cease to work.

Here's the javascript:

```
var blurPage = function() {
    $("body").addClass("noscroll"); //Add the noscroll class to body

    //This part just adds classes to elements within body

    var a = $('article.full').add('section.halfwrap');
    for (var i = 0; i <= a.length; i++) {
        if ($(a).hasClass('full')) {
            a.addClass('shadow');
        }
        var b = $(a[i]).children();
        for (var j = 0; j <= b.length; j++) {
            $(b[j]).addClass('blur');
        }
    }
    $('#post-main').addClass('active');
}
```

Here's the CSS:

```
body {
    background: #F7F4F2;
}
body.noscroll {
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

If I remove the overflow-y: hidden property from body.noscroll, the animations work just fine.

I also encounter the same problem if, instead of using a CSS class, I just do:

```
$('body').css("overflow-y", "hidden");
```

Comment: This has been around for a while, you can use the transitionEnd event to add the overflow when the transition has finished. 
Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions

Comment: Is this just a bug with CSS transitions? What causes it?

Comment: Yeah, at least in firefox: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=718000